# Creative Sound Blaster Z not working under Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: sound

I have a Creative Sound Blaster Z and am running Ubuntu 14.10.

I have been searching for quite a while about the problem with the Creative Sound Blaster Z not working under the 64-bit Linux Kernel.

Could someone help me to a similar solution as in the [solution for the Creative Recon3D card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398826/creative-recon-3d-sound-card-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10).

Comment: And your question is??? Please [edit] your question so that it is clear what you're asking. (and you'll definitely not going to grab Creative Labs attention in this forum, unless you cross-link)

Comment: I want someone to write some modification or driver(if worst comes to the worst) like the one used to fix the Creative Recon3D card. Here's the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/398826/creative-recon-3d-sound-card-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10.

Comment: I've edited your question to attract more attention.  As I'm just a low-level moderator, it still has to be peer-reviewed before you can see it.

Comment: Look at this place https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55541 but the problem is not agreed.

Comment: Since this question was bumped to the homepage i recommend testing with a newer kernel or Ubuntu release (14.10 is EOL anyway), Marc Bourgoin made a few comments in the bugzilla thread that kernel 4.4 or newer should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way I known to get sound out of this card, I have one and tried it.

It is form here:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2147443&page=4

First of all, ***BEFORE*** turn the PC you need to plug the speaker or headphone to the front panel headphone socket.

Then open a terminal(ctrl+alt+t) and run one of the follow line of code ***ASAP*** after logining in.(Because it ***sometimes*** work, depend on luck)[enter your user password when sudo ask for it]

```
sudo kill `ps uax |grep pulseaudio | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` ; sudo rmmod snd-hda-intel; sleep 3; sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

***OR***

```
sudo kill `ps uax |grep pulseaudio | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` ; sudo rmmod snd-hda-intel
//Then(This is not a command!)
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

Sometimes, you will need to run it twice.

If you encounter only one side sound out, then try `alsamixer` or `gnome-alsamixer` in terminal, check the sound level.

PS:It is really a hassle to change plug every time I change OS, so I could only stick with Windows.

Comment: Looks like a good solution will try when I am at home as I am currently abroad

Comment: Can you give me an alternative to using the front panel audio as I do not have.

Comment: As said, this is the only way i know of, front panel is the only way out for sound